# Android binder to service VS intent service

Tags: android

In early android ~ version 1.5, we need to bind to service like this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

But later on, android has new api called 'Intent Service'. And I don't see people talk about using binding to service as often.

So is it a recommend practice to use Intent service instead of binding to service?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

not completely.
If you need a worked thread probably with a que and want to execute one thread at a time.
Intentservice is good and simple to use.

Usually worker thread is required for long running process like webservice calls, playing music or downloading a file, etc.  But if you want download multiple files in a single request then you may need multiple threads or a AsyncTask which has got thread pool.

Now it is a better practice to execute this threads in a service.

If you need still clarification, can you post specific question?